# Having some issues with updating my GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm making a Hangman Windows Forms application and so far it's been coming along nicely, the logic is there, but I am having a smaller issue with the GUI synching.

Right now I am displaying the UI from a `GameForm.cs` which in turn instantiates a class called `GameRound` on a seperate thread, now the issue is kind of strange, the gameround loop works, the problem is, it doesn't update the UI elements(in this case a picturebox to display the hangman, a textbox to display the obscured word and a label to display already guessed characters) as they are called, instead they are update after each iteration of the loop. However I've noticed that if I insert a `MessageBox.Show()` into the loop then they'll be update as the messagebox is called.

I'm guessing this is some kind of thread synching issue, where the form doesn't want to update while the Gameround thread is working or something but I am a complete begineer programmer so I need some help!

Here's the code to Gameround(Gameround.Start())

```
    public void Start()
    {
        Hangman hangman = new Hangman();
        do
        {
            //Check if hangman is dead first
            if (hangman.HangmanStep == 6) {
                MessageBox.Show("You got hanged! RIP");
                complete = true; }

            bool w_reduceSticks = new bool();
            string output = WordBuilder.ObscureWord(word);

            HangManBox.Image = Drawing.Drawer.DrawHangMan(hangman.HangmanStep);

            WordBox.Text = output;
            GuessedLetters.Text = ReturnGuessedLetters(incorrectGuesses);
            MessageBox.Show("");

            //After guessing check if we've guessed all letters in the word
            if (CompareLists(word.dontObscure, word.letters.Distinct().ToList()))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                complete = true;
                break;
            }

            Thread readKeyThread = new Thread(InitReadKeyForm);
            readKeyThread.Start();
            readKeyThread.Join();

            if (ReadKeyForm.Key == 2) {
                w_reduceSticks = GuessWord();
            }
            else {
                w_reduceSticks = GuessLetters(ReadKeyForm.Key);
            }

            if (w_reduceSticks)
            {
                hangman.HangmanStep++;
            }
        } while (!complete);
```

Comment: The lower part of your code is not accessible because of the `break` after `Thread.Sleep(2000);`. But that's another problem.

Comment: Right that's just me debugging some stuff, I'm gonna edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think this is running in a separate thread? By all signs, it's obvious that it's running on the UI thread instead (you wouldn't be able to modify UI elements from outside of the UI thread). That's also why `MessageBox.Show` "helps". `Application.DoEvents` will do the same.

In any case, the core of the issue is that you're not actually running this in a separate thread. Show us the code you use to "start the new thread".

Comment: You're right, it's not a seperate thread, I am calling it from the same thread as the game forms. If I seperate it to another thread I will have to either modify my code quite bit though or find an easy way to update the UI elements from the game round thread.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive That's actually quite simple - you can use `Control.Invoke` to queue code to run on the UI thread at the nearest convenience :) So do all your work and logic, and when it's time to update the UI, just `Invoke` the code. Also, you might want to use `await` / `async` if you have access to .NET 4.5.1, it's awesome for asynchronous code that isn't CPU bound (in your case, the only blocking thing is waiting for a key (I/O bound) and `Thread.Sleep` (a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

You should always update your UI controls on the same thread that created them.

Have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52752/Updating-Your-Form-from-Another-Thread-without-Cre it explains how to update controls on the correct thread

Answer (score 0):

As people suggested, the reason that your ui thread does not update properly is because it doesn't get the priority to do so after your code in the game thread executes.
This can be solved by either adding `Application.DoEvents()` (which would tell the system pretty much let others work too) or using a Lock object to sync the two threads.
As a side note, because I started reading up on game programming too, it seems that the correct way (at least up to the point where you get to serious games, I have no idea what goes on there) to implement a game is something along these lines:

```
while (!finished){
    ProcessInputs();
    DoCalculations();
    DrawScreen();
}
```

So it seems that in these kind of applications, it is all done in the same thread. And it sorta makes sense, since it's not like commercial programs where you can send an sql query and you don't care how long it takes for it to show the user the results. In games you have  to have instant feedback to the user's actions.
Hope I helped

Comment: The reason most games are still mostly single threaded is how hard it is to make a great multi threaded game engine. 60 FPS means you only have 16 ms to process each frame, and synchronizing different threads, especially within that timeframe, is extremely tricky. Approaches that work in other software are often unusable (immutables are awesome for parallelization, but you usually can't afford the overhead in such low-latency scenarios). Your example (the SQL query) isn't actually relevant, since that's the classic I/O bound operation - something you can handle with `async` on the same thread.